# What does "supporting 3 independent screens" mean?

Tags: display, shuttle, barebone

[Here](http://global.shuttle.com/news/productsDetail?productId=1869) it says, Shuttle DS87 supports three independent displays.
What does this mean?

Usually, when we connect 2nd or 3rd monitor to a computer, aren't they independent?

I hope my question doesn't sound stupid... :)

Comment: You've just answered your own question :) independent screens means each one can have separate content displayed to the others. The usual combination might be a VGA, a DVI and a DisplayPort; or a VGA and two HDMI; or a HDMI and DisplayPort capable of multiple monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of older graphics cards supported a maximum of 2 displays and until recently 3 or more displays was considered niche. This is why people are currently stating explicitly that 3 displays are possible.

With older graphics cards that had more than 2 connectors but supported only running 2 of those independently, the extra displays usually had to be the same as one of the other displays, hence non-independent.

Most modern graphics cards support 3 or 4 displays using DisplayPort adaptors.